# Maven: Excluding log4j.properties from dependency

Tags: maven

My pom.xml file has 2 dependency and both of them have log4j.properties file. Is there a way to exclude the file in the dependency?

Using this plugin doesn't help:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The warning that I am getting:

[WARNING] Found duplicate resources in [org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:2.XXX,org.apache.hbase:hbase-test:2-XXX] :
[WARNING]   log4j.properties

Answer (score 0):

```
1. go to your pom choose Dependency Hierarchy tab
2.enter the jar name you want (log4j)
3.see if they are at the same version (you are expecting more then one)
4.exclude whatever you don't need (you can right click to exclude)
```

Comment: I am using intellij and I don't see any option to right click and exclude property file. Btw, both log4j.properties files are part of 2 different maven dependencies.

Comment: i am not familiar with intellij  but try to exclude the jar and not the properties hope it will help you